# Apply change to timedelta to columns containing a given string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

Be the following DataFrame in python pandas:

| date | time_SEL | time_02_SEL_01 | time_03_SEL_05 | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 34756 | 233232 | 3432423 | 756 |
| 2022-01-03 | 23322 | 4343 | 3334 | 343 |
| 2022-02-01 | 123232 | 3242 | 23423 | 434 |
| 2022-03-01 | 7323232 | 32423 | 323423 | 34324 |

All columns other than date represent a fraction of time in seconds. My idea is to pass these values to TimeDelta, keeping in mind that I only want to apply the change to columns containing the string "_SEL".

Naturally I want to apply them per string, because in the original dataset, there will be more than 3 columns with this string. If there were only 3, I would know how to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) on all columns selected by [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the original dataframe:

```
df.update(df.filter(like='_SEL').apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s'))
```

*NB. there is no output, the modification is inplace*

updated dataframe:

```
         date         time_SEL     time_02_SEL      time_03_SEL  other
0  2022-01-01  0 days 09:39:16 2 days 16:47:12 39 days 17:27:03    756
1  2022-01-03  0 days 06:28:42 0 days 01:12:23  0 days 00:55:34    343
2  2022-02-01  1 days 10:13:52 0 days 00:54:02  0 days 06:30:23    434
3  2022-03-01 84 days 18:13:52 0 days 09:00:23  3 days 17:50:23  34324
```

###### update "TypeError: invalid type promotion"

ensure you have numbers:

```
(df.update(df.filter(like='_SEL')
             .apply(lambda c: pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_numeric(c, errors='coerce'),
                                              unit='s'))
)
```

Comment: I get this error -> TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: what is the original type? check `df.dtypes` You need to ensure having integers (see update)

Comment: 'timedelta64[s]' I think

Comment: @Carola I meant before the conversion, did you test the update? If this fails, please provide the full error traceback and a sample of the real data (`df.head().to_dict()`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get all columns ends by `_SEL`, convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and replace original by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='_SEL$').apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='s')))
print (df)
         date         time_SEL     time_02_SEL      time_03_SEL  other
0  2022-01-01  0 days 09:39:16 2 days 16:47:12 39 days 17:27:03    756
1  2022-01-03  0 days 06:28:42 0 days 01:12:23  0 days 00:55:34    343
2  2022-02-01  1 days 10:13:52 0 days 00:54:02  0 days 06:30:23    434
3  2022-03-01 84 days 18:13:52 0 days 09:00:23  3 days 17:50:23  34324
```

Another idea is filter column by [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
m = df.columns.str.endswith('_SEL')
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='s'))
print (df)
         date         time_SEL     time_02_SEL      time_03_SEL  other
0  2022-01-01  0 days 09:39:16 2 days 16:47:12 39 days 17:27:03    756
1  2022-01-03  0 days 06:28:42 0 days 01:12:23  0 days 00:55:34    343
2  2022-02-01  1 days 10:13:52 0 days 00:54:02  0 days 06:30:23    434
3  2022-03-01 84 days 18:13:52 0 days 09:00:23  3 days 17:50:23  34324
```

EDIT: For convert values of columns to integers use `.astype(int)`:

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='_SEL$').astype(int).apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='s')))
```

If failed, because some non numeric values use:

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='_SEL$').apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'), unit='s')))
```

Comment: I get this error -> TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: @Carola - can you check EDIT?